# Fastest way to save NLog logs to Azure TableStorage

Tags: nlog, azure-table-storage

I have set up a POC that uses NLog to save log messages to Application Insights and Azure Table Storage. I have used the `AzureTableStorageNLogTarget` NuGet package by Harouny, but I'm not quite sure if it's the fastest way to save to Table Storage.

I need the log messages to be saved in batches for performance.
 Does Harouny do that, or should I use some fork? [JDetmar](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage) says he writes in batches, but does [Harouny](https://github.com/harouny/NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage) also do it? If anybody knows it, it would be nice.

I'll try to benchmark it to find out in the meantime and post my findings once I know more.

Comment: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage has batching logic. Have now created a PR with some improvements: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/pull/7 (Also for performance)

Comment: Thanks; I have seen that the code from Harouny faster is than the code of JDetmar. I'll test the extension AzureStorage to see if it's better.

Comment: Remember that AsyncTargetWrapper must be used to allow batching to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the log messages to be saved in batches for performance. Does Harouny do that, or should I use some fork? JDetmar says he writes in batches, but does Harouny also do it? If anybody knows it, it would be nice.

As the code is open-source, you could easily check that.

1. Locate the targets in both repos
2. Check if they override a `Write` method that accepts multiple logEvents (list or array), e.g. `override void Write(IList<AsyncLogEventInfo> logEvents)`

Results:

- JDetmar: Overrides `Write` with single and multiple logEvents, so works in batches when using a async wrapper. [see code](https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/599b2a20cd3c1dbad590f090ce4731a85b9889ec/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/TableStorageTarget.cs#L105-L144)
- Harouny:  Overrides `Write` with single logEvent, and not with multiple. So no batched writing. [see code](https://github.com/harouny/NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage/blob/92dfde81202139385f50b19e92bbe390209592d4/NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage/AzureTableStorageTarget.cs#L61-L75)

Please note that Harouny is not maintained. (see [readme](https://github.com/harouny/NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage/blob/master/README.md))